# 1980s superhero show; "stolen" bridge

Tags: story-identification, super-hero

In the early 80s I watched a live-action superhero TV show about which I can only remember fragments.

I think there was a team of heroes, but one member was just a normal human (no special skills at all, not even Batman/Hawkeye level).

The particular episode I remember is that a villain had apparently stolen the Golden Gate Bridge (or maybe the Brooklyn Bridge, or some other similarly famous one); but in fact all he'd done is hypnotise everyone to think it had gone, it was there all the time. The "normal" human wasn't affected for some reason; he tried to persuade the others that the bridge was still there, by walking out onto it, to their amazement as from their point of view he was standing on nothing.

Any clues at all? I would have watched this in Australia, but I don't think it was an Aussie production particularly. (Alternatively, maybe it was, and it was the Sydney Harbour Bridge that was stolen? Really can't remember.)

Comment: The description of the superheros sounds like [Misfits of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misfits_of_Science), but they didn't have an episode as you describe.